# Does Madden NFL 11 support  local multiplayer?

Tags: madden-11

I was looking for a game that my son and I could play together on our xbox.  I picked out the game Madden NFL 11.  My son asked "Are you sure we can do multi player on the same xbox?"  I told him that I thought so, but I better check before I open the game.

Is it possible for us to play together using the same console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Up to **four** players can play "offline" multiplayer, while up to **six** players can play over Xbox Live/PSN.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Madden NFL features an offline multiplayer mode that you can use to play together using one console.